# Low Replace Skips First Match in Same Line

Tags: low-replace, regex

I have a Low Replace tag that uses a regex to target links:

```
{exp:low_replace
    find='<a[^>]*href=QUOTE(.+)QUOTE[^>]*(.*)>(.*)<\/a>'
    replace='<a href=QUOTE$1QUOTE$2 style=QUOTEcolor: #007766; text-decoration: underline;QUOTE><span style=QUOTEcolor: #007766;QUOTE>$3</span></a>'
    regex='yes'
}
    <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Search on Google</a> <a href="http://bing.com" title="Search on Bing">or Bing</a>.
{/exp:low_replace}
```

But if the links are on the same line, Low Replace will only replace the last one. If I separate the links with a line break, like this:

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Search on Google</a> 
<a href="http://bing.com" title="Search on Bing">or Bing</a>.
```

then Low Replace works as expected.

I'm certain this is some problem with my regex, can anyone offer some insight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to make the any-character match not greedy using a `?`:

```
<a[^>]*?href=QUOTE(.+?)QUOTE[^>]*?(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>
```

That'll probably help.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I just tried making the changes you suggested, but it didn't work :/

Comment: Added another `?` just before the `href`. Try again?

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work.

Comment: Aaand another one after the `+`. Surely now it works?